# How to Enable Spell Checker in Solr

Tags: magento, solr

I'm working with Solr and Magento CE1.7.0.2

I hope its working fine upto search by name.But now i want to Enable Spell checker

I found Spell checker will not enable by default,so i have to enable it with myself with own code. For this I have to edit the code from the following files

1. schema.xml
2. solrconfig.xml

i got completed these two also here is my solr logs please take a look at this.

```
0    [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server  – jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
27   [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider  – Deployment monitor /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/contexts at interval 0
35   [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager  – Deployable added: /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml
1183 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor  – NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
1219 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – SolrDispatchFilter.init()
1233 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
1233 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – solr home defaulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
1234 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – new SolrResourceLoader for directory: 'solr/'
1363 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr  – Loading container configuration from /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/solr.xml
1473 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolrXml  – Config-defined core root directory: 
1481 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – New CoreContainer 18119756
1482 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Loading cores into CoreContainer [instanceDir=solr/]
1493 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting socketTimeout to: 0
1493 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting urlScheme to: http://
1493 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting connTimeout to: 0
1493 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting maxConnectionsPerHost to: 20
1495 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting corePoolSize to: 0
1495 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting maximumPoolSize to: 2147483647
1495 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting maxThreadIdleTime to: 5
1495 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting sizeOfQueue to: -1
1495 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting fairnessPolicy to: false
1599 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher  – SLF4J impl is org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
1600 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher  – Registering Log Listener [Log4j (org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory)]
1627 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Looking for core definitions underneath /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr
1641 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Found core collection1 in /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/
1641 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Found 1 core definitions
1643 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Creating SolrCore 'collection1' using instanceDir: /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1
1643 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/'
1710 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig  – Adding specified lib dirs to ClassLoader
1712 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar' to classloader
1712 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar' to classloader
1712 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/metadata-extractor-2.6.2.jar' to classloader
1712 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/tagsoup-1.2.1.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar' to classloader
1714 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/tika-core-1.4.jar' to classloader
1714 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/pdfbox-1.8.1.jar' to classloader
1714 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar' to classloader
1714 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/poi-3.9.jar' to classloader
1715 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar' to classloader
1715 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar' to classloader
1715 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/netcdf-4.2-min.jar' to classloader
1715 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/fontbox-1.8.1.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/icu4j-49.1.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/tika-parsers-1.4.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar' to classloader
1717 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar' to classloader
1717 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar' to classloader
1717 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/jdom-1.0.jar' to classloader
1717 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/jempbox-1.8.1.jar' to classloader
1718 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/xz-1.0.jar' to classloader
1718 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/rome-0.9.jar' to classloader
1719 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/dist/solr-cell-4.6.0.jar' to classloader
1720 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/mahout-math-0.6.jar' to classloader
1720 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/hppc-0.5.2.jar' to classloader
1721 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/attributes-binder-1.2.0.jar' to classloader
1721 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/simple-xml-2.7.jar' to classloader
1721 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/carrot2-mini-3.8.0.jar' to classloader
1721 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.4.jar' to classloader
1722 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/mahout-collections-1.0.jar' to classloader
1722 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.jar' to classloader
1723 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/dist/solr-clustering-4.6.0.jar' to classloader
1723 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/langid/lib/jsonic-1.2.7.jar' to classloader
1723 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/langid/lib/langdetect-1.1-20120112.jar' to classloader
1724 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/dist/solr-langid-4.6.0.jar' to classloader
1725 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/velocity/lib/velocity-tools-2.0.jar' to classloader
1725 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/velocity/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar' to classloader
1725 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/velocity/lib/velocity-1.7.jar' to classloader
1726 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/contrib/velocity/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar' to classloader
1727 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/dist/solr-velocity-4.6.0.jar' to classloader
1881 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexConfig  – IndexWriter infoStream solr logging is enabled
1886 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig  – Using Lucene MatchVersion: LUCENE_46
2018 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.Config  – Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
2023 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – Reading Solr Schema from schema.xml
2098 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – [collection1] Schema name=example
2575 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – unique key field: id
2644 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.FileExchangeRateProvider  – Reloading exchange rates from file currency.xml
2649 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.FileExchangeRateProvider  – Reloading exchange rates from file currency.xml
2767 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory
2773 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Opening new SolrCore at /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/, dataDir=/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/
2774 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.JmxMonitoredMap  – No JMX servers found, not exposing Solr information with JMX.
2778 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Added SolrEventListener for newSearcher: org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener{queries=[]}
2779 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Added SolrEventListener for firstSearcher: org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener{queries=[{q=static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml}]}
2791 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory  – return new directory for /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data
2791 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – New index directory detected: old=null new=/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/index/
2792 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory  – return new directory for /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/index
2801 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – created json: solr.JSONResponseWriter
2802 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – adding lazy queryResponseWriter: solr.VelocityResponseWriter
2802 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – created velocity: solr.VelocityResponseWriter
2805 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – created xslt: solr.XSLTResponseWriter
2805 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.response.XSLTResponseWriter  – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=5
2883 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – no updateRequestProcessorChain defined as default, creating implicit default
2892 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /select: solr.SearchHandler
2892 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /query: solr.SearchHandler
2894 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /get: solr.RealTimeGetHandler
2894 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /browse: solr.SearchHandler
2897 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /update: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
2898 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /update/json: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
2898 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /update/csv: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
2898 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
2899 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /update/extract: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
2899 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler
2899 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /analysis/field: solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler
2899 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler
2899 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /analysis/document: solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler
2901 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /admin/: solr.admin.AdminHandlers
2903 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /admin/ping: solr.PingRequestHandler
2906 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /debug/dump: solr.DumpRequestHandler
2918 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /replication: solr.ReplicationHandler
2918 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2918 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /spell: solr.SearchHandler
2919 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /myMainRequestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2919 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2919 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /tvrh: solr.SearchHandler
2919 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: org.apache.solr.handler.js.JavaScriptRequestHandler
2919 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /js: org.apache.solr.handler.js.JavaScriptRequestHandler
2919 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2920 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /terms: solr.SearchHandler
2920 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2920 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /elevate: solr.SearchHandler
2934 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader  – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
2936 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader  – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
2937 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader  – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
2963 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – Hard AutoCommit: if uncommited for 15000ms; 
2963 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – Soft AutoCommit: disabled
2997 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – SolrDeletionPolicy.onInit: commits: num=1
    commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@1016c4e; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_bj,generation=415}
2998 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – newest commit generation = 415
3015 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher  – Opening Searcher@6622c9 main
3020 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – Initializing spell checkers
3026 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.spelling.DirectSolrSpellChecker  – init: {name=default,field=textSpell,spellcheckIndexDir=./spellchecker,classname=solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker,distanceMeasure=internal,accuracy=0.5,maxEdits=2,minPrefix=1,maxInspections=5,minQueryLength=4,maxQueryFrequency=0.01}
3032 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – No queryConverter defined, using default converter
3034 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent  – Loading QueryElevation from: /root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/conf/elevate.xml
3060 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler  – Commits will be reserved for  10000
3060 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@6622c9 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_bj:835:nrt _7v(4.6):C28)}
3061 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – registering core: collection1
3064 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – user.dir=/root/Desktop/solr/solr-4.6.0/example
3065 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
3101 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  – Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
3122 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=null path=null params={event=firstSearcher&q=static+firstSearcher+warming+in+solrconfig.xml&distrib=false} hits=0 status=0 QTime=59 
3123 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – QuerySenderListener done.
3123 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – Loading spell index for spellchecker: default
3123 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – Loading spell index for spellchecker: wordbreak
3123 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@6622c9 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_bj:835:nrt _7v(4.6):C28)}
```

I found in these some technical words like **Loading spell index for spellchecker: default** i think spellchecker initialization is done successfully.

& i have one doubt to show the **do you mean :** option in frontend i have to write some code some where...

Any thing wrong i did here ?

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

once you edit code in **solrconfig.xml** and **schema.xml**, you can request to build spellchecker index.

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/spell?q=some query&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.build=true
```

Note: you don't need to include the last part of the query in each request because this will build the spelling index all time you request.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/spell?q=some query&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true
```

In the previous XML section don't forget to replace the field spell by the field on which you want to build your spellchecker against.